# generate random dates where delta between another date column is exponentially distributed in python

Tags: pandas

How can I generate a date column `shipping_date` (either in `2019` or `2020`), where the difference between `sale_date` and `shipping_dat`e is exponentially distributed? (and `shipping_date` comes before `sales_date`)

Let's say this is my dataset in `YYYY-MM_DD` format:

```
ID      Sale Date       Shipping Date
5464    2019-01-06  
5423    2020-01-07  
3490    2019-04-08  
3945    2019-03-09  
2387    2019-10-10  
2393    2019-11-11  
2395    2020-01-12  
4331    2019-04-13  
3982    2019-05-14  
1875    2019-08-15
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: random "shipping_dates", = (sales_date - delta),  where delta is positive and exponentially distributed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the scipy package for this problem; see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html

You can do something of the following:

```
from scipy.stats import expon

df['delta'] = pd.Series(expon.rvs(scale=1, size=len(df)))
```

Note the scale parameter you can set. Please see the documentation link above. After you have done this, just use pandas to subtract the column 'delta' from 'Sale Date' using the usual time difference techniques.